# Mutating arrays is not supported in Zygote

Tags: julia

I am trying to code the spiral example from [example](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq/blob/master/examples/ode_demo.py) in Julia with the [scientific machine learning framework](https://sciml.ai/)

However, when the code differentiates through the `get_batch` function I get the error:

`ERROR: Mutating arrays is not supported -- called setindex!(Vector{Int64}, ...) This error occurs when you ask Zygote to differentiate operations that change the elements of arrays in place (e.g. setting values with x .= ...)`

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
  using Lux, DiffEqFlux, DifferentialEquations, ComponentArrays, Random, StatsBase, MLUtils
  using Zygote

  true_y0 = [2., 0.];
  true_A = [-0.1 2.; -2. -0.1];

  data_size = 1000;
  times = LinRange(0, 25, data_size);

  function ground_truth!(du, u, p, t)
      du .= true_A * (u.^3) 
  end

  ground_truth_odeProb = ODEProblem(ground_truth!, true_y0, (0, times[end]));

  sol_ode = Array(
                    solve(ground_truth_odeProb,
                          Tsit5(),
                          abstol = 1e-10, reltol = 1e-10,
                          saveat = times)
                  );

  batch_time = 10
  batch_size = 20

  function get_batch()

    s = sample(range(1, data_size - batch_time), batch_size, replace=false)

    batch_y0 = sol_ode[ :, s];
    
    batch_t = times[1:batch_time];

    batch_y = stack([sol_ode[:, s .+ i] for i in range(1, batch_time)], dims=3);

    return [batch_y0, batch_t, batch_y];

  end

  const neural_net = Lux.Chain(Lux.Dense(2, 50, tanh),
                        Lux.Dense(50, 2))     

  rng = Random.default_rng();
  p, st = Lux.setup(rng, neural_net)

  const _st = st;

  p_init = ComponentArray(p);

  function neural_net_func!(du, u, p, t)
    du .= neural_net(u.^3, p, st)[1];
  end

  prob_nn = ODEProblem(neural_net_func!, [0., 0.], [0., 0.], p);

  function predict(θ, y0s, ts)
    
    _prob = remake( prob_nn, 
                    u0 = y0s, 
                    tspan = (ts[1], ts[end]), 
                    p = θ
                  );
    
    Array(solve(_prob, Tsit5(), saveat = ts,
              abstol = 1e-5, reltol = 1e-5)); 
  end

  function test(θ)
    y0s, ts, targets = get_batch();
    pred = predict(θ, y0s, ts);
    loss = sum(abs2, targets .- pred)
  end

  x, lambda = pullback((θ) -> test(θ), p_init,);

  lambda(x) # give the error
```

Answer (score 2):

The title already pretty much tells you what the problem is: Zygote, the automatic differentiation (AD) library, doesn't support mutating arrays, but you do mutate arrays in your RHS.

In fact many AD libraries don't support mutation. As AD relies on tracking each operation that is performed by your method, it is technically quite challenging to support mutating operations.

Your example is not really that minimal, so I didn't run it. But to me it seems that there is probably an easy fix: If you look at the definition of the RHS `neural_net_func!`, it's quite easy to avoid the mutation: just define it in an out-of-place style, so write a function

```
neural_net_func(u,p,t) = neural_net(u.^3, p, st)[1];
```

I suspect that this could already fix your problem. If you look at the error message, this is also already what the error message suggests you to do as well!

If this doesn't help, there are more generally other ways around this:

- Use Enzyme as an AD library: Enzyme is one of the few AD libraries that actually does support mutation. In order to use it, you need to tell `SciMLSensitivity` in the `solve` command. See the documentation for more info: https://docs.sciml.ai/SciMLSensitivity/stable/
- Define custom adjoints when mutation can't be avoided, but you want to keep using Zygote: ChainRules.jl is the library for that https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ChainRules.jl

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. 

The line `neural_net_func(u,p,t) = neural_net(u.^3, p, st)[1];` did not work for me.

When I run the code. It tells me that the error is in `s = sample(range(1, data_size - batch_time), batch_size, replace=false)` and I do not know why.

Comment: Then reduce your problem further and take the `get_batch` function outside of the function you want to differentiate. If this works (with some arbitrary inputs), then you can work on fixing the `get_batch` function. Read the error messages careful. What it is complaining about in this line?